# Can you sim a fight and level heroes?

Tags: injustice-2-mobile

As far as I can tell when you simulate a fight you only earn the reward drops at the end of the fight that you would usually get. This means that the heroes in your current team won't earn xp and so won't continue to level up.

You can set your team fighting and use auto play so the AI plays for you but this *probably* takes longer than playing yourself and it means the fight is not a guaranteed win like a sim fight.

Is there a way to sim the fight **and** level the heroes in your team?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the AI doesn't actually fight for you. Everytime I used a SIM I just get the rewards with no fight at all.

Comment: @Ramirez I meant if you play the fight and then enable auto play instead of using sim.

Comment: @Ramirez It's the button with two right hand arrows in it next to pause in the fight. Makes the AI play your team for you, though they aren't the best fighters...